# l3build testing several tcolorbox theorems: what would be the best way?

Tags: standalone, package-writing, documentclass-writing, l3build

(I'm (still) in the process of trying to understand how `l3build` tests work.)

Suppose I'd like to `l3build` a test for a class (based on `standalone` class, but I guess it is of little importance here) which will define the following
`tcolorbox`' theorems environments.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=15cm,border=1in,french]{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{zref-clever}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}
\tcbset{label is zlabel}

\tcbset{
  commonstyle/.style 2 args = {
    , fonttitle=\bfseries
    , IfEmptyF={#2}{after title={~(#2)}}
    , IfValueT={#1}{#1}
  },
  commonstyle numbered/.style 2 args = {
    , commonstyle={#1}{#2}
    , after title pre={~\thetcbcounter}
  },
  theorem-style/.style={
    , fontupper=\itshape
    , colback=red!10!white
    , colframe=red!75!black
  },
  definition-style/.style={
    , colback=green!10!white
    , colframe=green!75!black
  },
}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{theorem}{ o m }{%
  , commonstyle numbered={#1}{#2}
  , theorem-style
  , label type=theorem
  , title={Théorème}
}
\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{proposition}{ o m }{%
  , commonstyle numbered={#1}{#2}
  , theorem-style
  , title={Proposition}
  , label type=proposition
}
\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{corollary}{ o m }{%
  , commonstyle numbered={#1}{#2}
  , theorem-style
  , title={Corollaire}
  , label type=corollary
}
\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{definition}{ o m }{%
  , commonstyle numbered={#1}{#2}
  , definition-style
  , title={Définition}
  , label type=definition
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dummytext}{}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[label={interesting}]{interesting}
  \dummytext{}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{}
  \dummytext{}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}[label={beautiful}]{beautiful}
  \dummytext{}
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}{}
  \dummytext{}
\end{proposition}

\begin{corollary}[label={correlated}]{correlated}
  \dummytext{}
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}{}
  \dummytext{}
\end{corollary}

\begin{definition}[label={clever}]{clever}
  \dummytext{}
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{}
  \dummytext{}
\end{definition}

\zref[cap]{interesting}, \zref{interesting}, \zref{beautiful},
\zref{correlated}, \zref{clever}. 
\end{document}
```

If I understand well, the beginning of a test file would (could) be:

```
% Test file (beginning)
\input{regression-test.tex}
\documentclass[varwidth=15cm,border=1in,french]{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{zref-clever}

\usepackage[enable-debug,check-declarations]{expl3}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}
\tcbset{label is zlabel}

\tcbset{
  commonstyle/.style 2 args = {
    , fonttitle=\bfseries
    , IfEmptyF={#2}{after title={~(#2)}}
    , IfValueT={#1}{#1}
  },
  commonstyle numbered/.style 2 args = {
    , commonstyle={#1}{#2}
    , after title pre={~\thetcbcounter}
  },
  theorem-style/.style={
    , fontupper=\itshape
    , colback=red!10!white
    , colframe=red!75!black
  },
}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{theorem}{ o m }{%
  , commonstyle numbered={#1}{#2}
  , theorem-style
  , label type=theorem
  , title={Théorème}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dummytext}{}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.%
}

\begin{document}
\START
```

For the rest of this file, it is not clear for me from the documentation what
would be the best for my purpose:

1. Testing each theorem environment:

   1. independently or not?
   2. If yes, in the same test file or each in its own test file?
2. For instance for the `theorem` environment, would it be better to rely:

   1. on showing box content (section “2.3 Showing box content” of the
      documentation):

      ```
      % Test file (continuation)
      \ExplSyntaxOn
      \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box {#1}
      \box_show:N \l_tmpb_box {
        \begin{theorem}[label={interesting}]{interesting}
          \dummytext{}
        \end{theorem}

        \begin{theorem}{}
          \dummytext{}
        \end{theorem}

        \zref[cap]{interesting}, \zref{interesting}.
      }
      \ExplSyntaxOff
      \end{document}
      ```
   2. on testing entire pages (section “2.4 Testing entire pages” of the
      documentation):

      ```
       % Test file (alternative continuation)
       \begin{theorem}[label={interesting}]{interesting}
         \dummytext{}
       \end{theorem}

      \begin{theorem}{}
        \dummytext{}
      \end{theorem}

      \zref[cap]{interesting}, \zref{interesting}.
      \vfil\break
      \showlists
      \end{document}
      ```

Answer (score 2):

You really need to decide what you want to test.

eg if you show all box content  you will get a fail if  tcolorbox changes some internal box nesting. Perhaps you want to test for that, but perhaps you don't want to make every test dependent on every external package.

If you just want to check the correct font is used, don't use `\showbox` (or `\showlists`) have a test that just does `\showthe\font` inside each type of theorem.

If a change in babel makes zref-clever incompatible with babel you might get errors just loading the packages, so probably have one test with `\START` before the class (and an empty `document`) just to check it loads.

The important point is that l3build will only tell you that something has changed. If for example you have a test that does `\showthe\font` and some future change accidentally makes the default family latin modern  you will get a one line diff showing

```
> \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .
<recently read> \font
```

changed to

```
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 .
<recently read> \font
```

If on the other hand you add `\showoutput\showlists` to your example document it in principle tests a lot more things, but that same change would make a diff as below that you would need to inspect to verify it is an acceptable change. Whether this is  useful diff to inspect is a personal decision.

[diff truncated as too big for this site]

```
705c734
< \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ,
---
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 ,
707,710c736,737
< \hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.86105
< .\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?
< .\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?
< \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ,
---
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 1
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 ,
712,715c739,740
< \hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.86105
< .\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?
< .\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?
< \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ,
---
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 1
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 ,
717,720c742,743
< \hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.86105
< .\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?
< .\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?
< \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ,
---
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 1
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 ,
722,725c745,746
< \hbox(6.94444+0.0)x10.86105
< .\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?
< .\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?
< \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .
---
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 1
> \OT1/lmr/m/n/10 .
732,733c753,754
< \hbox(57.91887+0.0)x426.79134
< .\hbox(57.91887+0.0)x426.79134
---
> \hbox(57.86316+0.0)x426.79134
> .\hbox(57.86316+0.0)x426.79134
744c765
< .....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted -45.91887
---
> .....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted -45.86316
763,766c784,787
< ....\pdfliteral{0.0 53.45123 l }
< ....\pdfliteral{0.0 55.79958 1.90364 57.70322 4.25198 57.70322 c }
< ....\pdfliteral{420.95033 57.70322 l }
< ....\pdfliteral{423.29868 57.70322 425.20232 55.79958 425.20232 53.45123 c }
---
> ....\pdfliteral{0.0 53.39572 l }
> ....\pdfliteral{0.0 55.74406 1.90364 57.64772 4.25198 57.64772 c }
> ....\pdfliteral{420.95033 57.64772 l }
> ....\pdfliteral{423.29868 57.64772 425.20232 55.74406 425.20232 53.39572 c }
778,779c799,800
< ....\pdfliteral{1.41731 39.23647 l }
< ....\pdfliteral{423.785 39.23647 l }
---
> ....\pdfliteral{1.41731 39.18097 l }
> ....\pdfliteral{423.785 39.18097 l }
792c813
< .....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted -46.15099
---
> .....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted -46.09528
803c824
< ..........\hbox(7.5+2.5)x395.4934, glue set 269.50652fil
---
> ..........\hbox(7.5+2.5)x395.4934, glue set 269.5063fil
805,826c826,849
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 T
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 h
< ...........\kern -0.23958 (for accent)
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ^^S
< ...........\kern -5.51039 (for accent)
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 o
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 r
< ...........\kern -0.23958 (for accent)
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ^^R
< ...........\kern -5.51039 (for accent)
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 m
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
< ...........\penalty 10000
< ...........\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91666 minus 1.27777
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 1
< ...........\penalty 10000
< ...........\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91666 minus 1.27777
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 (
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 n
---
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 T
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 h
> ...........\kern -0.2395 (for accent)
> ...........\hbox(6.85724+0.0)x5.74998, shifted 0.11725
> ............\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 ^^S
> ...........\kern -5.51048 (for accent)
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 o
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 r
> ...........\kern -0.2395 (for accent)
> ...........\hbox(6.85724+0.0)x5.74998, shifted 0.11725
> ............\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 ^^R
> ...........\kern -5.51048 (for accent)
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 m
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 e
> ...........\penalty 10000
> ...........\glue 3.83333 plus 1.91667 minus 1.27777
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 1
> ...........\penalty 10000
> ...........\glue 3.83333 plus 1.91667 minus 1.27777
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 (
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 n
828,837c851,860
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 t
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 r
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 s
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 t
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 n
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 g
< ...........\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 )
---
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 t
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 r
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 s
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 t
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 n
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 g
> ...........\OT1/lmr/bx/n/10 )
854c877
< .....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted -11.90286
---
> .....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted -11.90285
858c881
< .......\hbox(18.94444+1.94444)x395.4934
---
> .......\hbox(18.88875+1.94443)x395.4934
860,861c883,884
< ........\hbox(18.94444+1.94444)x395.4934
< .........\vbox(18.94444+1.94444)x395.4934
---
> ........\hbox(18.88875+1.94443)x395.4934
> .........\vbox(18.88875+1.94443)x395.4934
865c888
< ..........\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x395.4934, glue set - 0.249
---
> ..........\hbox(6.88875+1.94443)x395.4934, glue set - 0.24904
867c890
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 L
---
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 L
869,870c892,893
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 r
---
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 r
872,963c895,986
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 m
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 p
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 s
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 u
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 m
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 d
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 l
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 r
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 s
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 t
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 a
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 m
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 t
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 ,
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53485 minus 1.02118
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 c
< ...........\kern-0.51112
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 n
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 s
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\kern-0.51112
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 c
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 t
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 t
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 u
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 r
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 a
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 d
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 p
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 s
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 c
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 n
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 g
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 l
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 t
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 ,
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53485 minus 1.02118
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 s
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\kern-0.51112
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 d
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 d
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 u
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 s
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 m
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\kern-0.51112
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 d
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 t
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 m
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 p
< ...........\kern-0.51112
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 r
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 n
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 c
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 d
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 d
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 u
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 n
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 t
---
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 m
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 p
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 s
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 u
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 m
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 d
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 l
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 r
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 s
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 t
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 a
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 m
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 t
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 ,
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53485 minus 1.02118
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 c
> ...........\kern-0.51112
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 n
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 s
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\kern-0.51112
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 c
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 t
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 t
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 u
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 r
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 a
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 d
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 p
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 s
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 c
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 n
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 g
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 l
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 t
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 ,
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53485 minus 1.02118
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 s
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\kern-0.51112
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 d
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 d
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 u
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 s
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 m
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\kern-0.51112
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 d
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 t
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 m
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 p
> ...........\kern-0.51112
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 r
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 n
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 c
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 d
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 d
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 u
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 n
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 t
966,1003c989,1026
< ..........\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
< ..........\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x395.4934, glue set 252.12776fil
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 u
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 t
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 l
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 a
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 b
< ...........\kern-0.51112
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 r
< ...........\kern-0.51112
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 t
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 d
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 l
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 r
< ...........\kern-0.51112
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 e
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 m
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 a
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 g
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 n
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 a
< ...........\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 a
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 l
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 i
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 q
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 u
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 a
< ...........\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 .
---
> ..........\glue(\baselineskip) 3.16682
> ..........\hbox(6.88875+1.94443)x395.4934, glue set 252.1282fil
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 u
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 t
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 l
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 a
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 b
> ...........\kern-0.51112
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 r
> ...........\kern-0.51112
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 t
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 d
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 l
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 o
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 r
> ...........\kern-0.51112
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 e
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 m
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 a
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 g
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 n
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 a
> ...........\glue 3.57777 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 a
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 l
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 i
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 q
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 u
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 a
> ...........\OT1/lmr/m/it/10 .
```

Comment: About your first advice: so would it be better to test the cross references in another test file, where the theorems themselves would be omitted?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I expanded the answer a bit